Are the two notions of subgaussian variable equivalent?
I have seen the following two definitions of subgaussian so far:
Definition 1:

Definition 2:

It seems like the only major difference between the two is the constant $2$ in the front. Is there a way to show Definition 1 implies Definition 2? I tried to rescale $v$ to some $v'$ so that $C$ can be adjusted to $2$, but because this rescaling involves $t$, which won't work as $v'$ should be independent of $t$. Any advice on how to derive this?

Definition 1 $\Longrightarrow$ Definition 2: Let $X$ be a random variable satisfies condition of Definition 1:
$$
    \mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert \ge t) \le C e^{-vt^2} \ \forall t \ge 0
$$
for some positive constant $v, C$. Consider the following cases:

Case 1. $0 < C \le 2$. Then,
$$
    \mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert \ge t) \le C e^{-vt^2} \le 2 e^{-vt^2} \ \forall t \ge 0
$$
Thus $X$ satisfies condition of Definition 2 with $K_1^2 = \dfrac{1}{v}$
Case 2. $C > 2$. In this case, since
$$
      C e^{-vt^2} \ge 1 \ \forall t \in \left[0, \sqrt{\dfrac{\ln C}{v}}\right]
$$
It is therefore sufficient to find $K_1$ such that
$$
     C e^{-vt^2} \le 2 e^{-t^2/K_1^2} \ \forall t > \sqrt{\dfrac{\ln C}{v}} 
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
     \left(v - \dfrac{1}{K_1^2}\right)t^2 \ge \ln\left(\dfrac{C}{2}\right)\ \forall t > \sqrt{\dfrac{\ln C}{v}} 
$$
One such choice for $K_1$ is to choose $K_1$ such that
$$
     \dfrac{1}{K_1^2} = \dfrac{v}{\log_2 C} > 0
$$
What left to do is to prove that $X$ satisfies Definition 2 with this choice of $K_1$: Indeed, when $t > \sqrt{\dfrac{\ln C}{v}}$:
$$
     \mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert \ge t) \le Ce^{-vt^2} \le 2 e^{-t^2/K_1^2}
$$
and when $t \in \left[0, \sqrt{\dfrac{\ln C}{v}} \right]$,
$$
    \mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert \ge t) \le 1 \le 2e^{-t^2/K_1^2}
$$

